# Magento 2 Customer Group not showing

Tags: magento2, customer-group

I found an issue on Magento 2.2.3 Customer Group.

What I did is create a new customer group named "tabellone"

Then I created i new user and selected that group: http://nimb.ws/fzQRm5

Then if I go on customers I can't see the group i just created and assigned to customer: http://nimb.ws/KTy7NJ

Also if I edit the row there is not such crated group: http://nimb.ws/malgRW

There are just the 3 defaults groups "Retailer, Wholsale, General"

I tested on my magento and on other magento.

Is that a bug?

David

Comment: Did You have run the magento reindex command after creating. @user2478262

Comment: After full cache refreshing it start showing.
Thank you very much for suggestion